# Calculating time complexity of a Turing Machine for a given input

Tags: time-complexity, turing-machines

I have been stuck in understanding a problem where I have an instance of a Turing Machine like in the link below:
[instance of turning machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq9Ks.jpg)

we have an input 'baacbaa' which is accepted by this turning machine in 32 steps. 
The goal is to calculate the time complexity for this input coming out as O(n^2).
The steps to do it are somewhat like:
n+2 moves for checking and replacing, n+1 moves backwards.

Compiling:

```
(2n+3)n=2n^2+3n 
(2n+3)n+ (n+2)= 2n^2+4n+2   ~O(n^2)
```

Please view the picture for detailed description as it is a bit complicated to type: 
[calculated time complexity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv1UF.jpg)

can someone please explain why there are n+2 moves for checking and replacing and n+1 moves backwards.
Also for inputs with odd length why was n replaced with n-1.

I have been stuck on it for quite a while now and not able to find good explanation anywhere. 
Thank you